# Get DOM element from FormControl, Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My custom form validator gets FormControl argumet and I want to get access to native DOM element. How can I get DOM element using FormControl object?

```
fileValidator(control: FormControl):{[key: string]: boolean}{
...
}
```

I need property files from input type="file" element.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. But you can use `@ViewChild` to get a reference to the DOM element.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. `@ViewChild` works fine.